# Hide image after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way using HTML and CSS can I hide an image after 10 seconds? If it's not possible, is there any easy way to do it with just JavaScipt (not jQuery, I don't want to add jQuery library to my HTML page unless its highly required).

Comment: What actually you cannot get? How to do something after 10 seconds or how to remove a node from the DOM? I'm sure both of these tasks is easily googleable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To hide instantly** -

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('imageID').style.display='none'
}, 10*1000);
```

**EDIT:**- **To animate hide using pure JS**

```
function start(){

window.timerID =  setInterval(function() {
var aOpaque = document.getElementById('imageID').style.opacity;
aOpaque = aOpaque-.1;

aOpaque = aOpaque.toFixed(1);   

document.getElementById('imageID').style.opacity = aOpaque;

if(document.getElementById('imageID').style.opacity<=0)
clearInterval(window.timerID);
},1000);
}

window.onload = function(){start();}
```

In the markup `<image id="imageID" style="opacity:1">` remember to give `style="opacity:1"` inline css attribute.

Please note that as `<img>` has an `alt` attribute that might affect search results of the page and doing a `display:none` might adversely impact the search results so developers use something like - `transform: translateX();` and just put the html tag out of the view say by giving a negative value in the `translateX(value)`.

Comment: is there any way to slowly hide? as it is hiding in a flash.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`setTimeOut()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)  for this

> setTimeout() - executes a function, once, after waiting a specified
>   number of milliseconds

```
setTimeout(function(){HIDE HERE)},10000);
```

Comment: Is there a way to slowly hide the image? currently its being hidden in a flash.

Comment: it is possible with jQuery

Comment: it is possible without jQuery

Comment: @lan sorry i dont know with out jQuery

Comment: Can yo please tell me how can I make it using jQuery?

Comment: Possible without `css3/jQuery/js lib` i.e. pure using pure `Javascript`

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){setTimeout(showPopup,10000)};

function showPopup()
{
   //write functionality for the code here
}
</script>
```

Here , the method `showPopup`
 is called 10000 milliseconds or 10 seconds after the `document` has loaded.

To achieve the `fading out` in pure JavaScript, the code becomes a bit more complicated.See edited answer below.This is not entirely my code but I don't remember from where I had got this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var fading_div = document.getElementById('fading_div');
var animationComplete = true;
window.onload=function(){setTimeout(hideImage,10000)};

function hideImage()
{
   if (animationComplete && fading_div.style.opacity !== '0') {
        animationComplete = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout((function (x) {
                return function () {
                    function_fade_out(x)
                };
            })(100 - i), i * 10);
        }
    }
}

function function_opacity(opacity_value) 
{
    fading_div.style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    fading_div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity_value + ')';
}

function function_fade_out(opacity_value) 
{
    function_opacity(opacity_value);
    if (opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'none';
        animationComplete = true;
    }
}
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<img id="fading_div" src="test_image.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use css3 and @keyframes. Set the keyframe and make it transparent after however long you'd like. Here is more info. [About Keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Comment: I don't see the use of css3 keyframes here

Comment: the original question was if he could use html and css, so I gave an answer that could work with css3. setTimeout() would work too, but the rest of the people already gave that answer.

Comment: Of course you are right @DeveloperLooper but I am worried CSS3 may not support IE and other older version browsers.

Comment: @Kerry understandable. Good luck with your project, though.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say anything about CSS2 or CSS3, but take a look at this... Maybe it can help you on the way?

[Demo on JsFiddle](http://bit.ly/12rTF53)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('//your image id').style.display='none'
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed the following code with Python and Conda

In Python, Output is displayed.

In Conda, Output is disappeared immediately, What to do?

## threshold.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

## Image operation using thresholding

```
img = cv2.imread('c4.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV +
                            cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('image', thresh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your code , image will be displayed and if you press <kbd>q</kbd> then the ouput window will be closed

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
   break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: add these lines to your code , image will be displayed and if you press 'q' then the ouput window will be closed